# Insight messages not showing in Visual Studio or Azure

Tags: azure-application-insights

Im seeing AI messages in the debug window  but not in the diagnostics window/ hub , Azure  or the application insights VS screens,

Debug window 
Application Insights Telemetry: {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.e71aa06ae1d142b4ae04393d63a71d57.Exception","time":"2016-07-16T09:46:37.7435251Z","iKey":"xyz","tags": etc

Not using a config file

```
        for (;;)
        {
            var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
            telemetryClient.InstrumentationKey = "abc";
            telemetryClient.Context.Session.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            telemetryClient.Context.User.AccountId = "Ben";
            telemetryClient.Context.Component.Version = "1.0";
            telemetryClient.TrackEvent("Application Start");

            telemetryClient.TrackException(new ApplicationException("test exc"));
            telemetryClient.Flush();
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }
```

This is in several solutions One a Console the other .Core . Any ideas ?

Add diagnostics shows.
Value for property 'Failed to load an item from the storage. file: 20160531051527_dbd26772482e4dbab6791b63f0ded9d3.trn Exception: System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel.Storage.Peek()' of vshub.exe was not found. Populating it by default.: OnNext: {0}
Value for property 'Failed to load transmission from file. File full path: C:\Users\bklooste\AppData\Local\Microsoft\ApplicationInsights\vstelAIF-312cbd79-9dbb-4c48-a7da-3cc2a931cb70\20160712090841_9436f519411b4a10b4f551897382fcc6.trn, Exception: System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel.Storage.d__14.MoveNext()' of vshub.exe was not found. Populating it by default.: OnNext: {0}
Value for property 'Failed to load an item from the storage. file: 20160712090841_9436f519411b4a10b4f551897382fcc6.trn Exception: System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)

Comment: That stack trace is being generated by vshub.exe which I don't suspect is the name of your application. If you're seeing the telemetry being sent in the debug window and you can validate that the Instrumentation Key is correct then there may be a proxy blocking the telemtry.

Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel.Storage.d__14.MoveNext()' of **vshub.exe** was not found.

Comment: Thought it maybe using vshub to communicate with the debugger. I got it going .. the key was wrong as always but the other thing strange was I do see them in Visual studio debug session now but never the first debugging session. It appears on the 2nd or 3rd - I still see the exceptions but its working,.

Comment: Gotcha, there is another mechanism for capturing the method calls that show up in the AI Window.

In this case what's happening is vshub is using a persistence channel to capture metrics while there is no internet connection. The message indicates there is some kind of corruption in the transmission file. If you delete the files in `C:\Users\bklooste\AppData\Local\Microsoft\ApplicationInsights\vstelAIF-312cbd79-9dbb-4c48-a7da-3cc2a931cb70` it should make this error message go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Possibly not an answer but will help those who search for this stack trace and don't read the comments on the question.*

The OPs question was resolved when they checked the Instrumentation Key.

The stack trace is generated by **vshub.exe** when it attempts to read the files at `C:\Users\bklooste\AppData\Local\Microsoft\ApplicationInsights\vstelAIF-312cbd79‌​-9dbb-4c48-a7da-3cc2a931cb70` to send in the offline telemetry.

This offline telemetry is provided by the [Application Insights Persisted HTTP](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PersistenceChannel/) package. Without knowing the actual contents of the file it seems likely there is some corruption in the file. The file should look something like the snippet below. If for some reason the file was truncated or the URI is actually malformed then this exception will be thrown.

You either need to correct the URI, or (preferrably) just delete the file.

```
https://vortex.data.microsoft.com/collect/v1
Content-Type:application/x-json-stream
Content-Encoding:gzip

H4sIAAAAAAAEAJV...
```

Comment: given that the data is being sent to vortex instead of AI, this appears to be Visual Studio's internal use of AI sdks to collect *its own telemetry*, not the OP's telemetry.